# What is the reason 'getSharedPreferences' method called by not making instance of ContextWrapper in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

i wrote code like below,

```
val preference by lazy {
    getSharedPreferences("PreExActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```

and got a wonder that the root of 'getSharedPredferences' methods..

so I found API..

```
public class ContextWrapper extends Context {
    @Override
    public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
        return mBase.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
    }
}
```

Is it correct to use getSharedPreferences method what i wrote in first code?

I think..

```
ContextWrapper().getSharedPreferences("PreExActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

is the way to use that method.

how can it possible?

Comment: You've left out the important part of what class the `preference` property belongs to. For example, an `Activity` extends `ContextWrapper`.

Comment: Sorry to miss it.. 'preference' belongs to Activity extends AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're calling the `getSharedPreferences` method from your `AppCompatActivity`.
This is perfectly correct.

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, which extends `ComponentActivity`, which extends `Activity`, which extends `ContextThemeWrapper`, which extends `ContextWrapper`, which extends `Context`. `Context` is an `abstract` class that actually defines the `getSharedPreferences` method(s).

Calling `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` method using `Activity` is actually calling `ContextWrapper`'s `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` since `Activity` inherits it.